# A heck load of gunk and stuff

Tags: cipher

Warning: lots of gunk- Can you make it through the tunnels?

```
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
```

Double click the line of text to select it all.

Hint:

> For step 3 you have to replace the symbols for other symbols for the 1st group. Now look at the symbols- what *language* does it remind you of??

Comment: Thx @humn Didnt think of that

Comment: No problem, ever more tunnely

Comment: @bleh Is it possible that my keyboard is different than yours and that this could be causing difficulty?

Answer (score 3):

Partial Answer

Step 1:

> Hex to Ascii
>  "Sometimes, there is a way out of a tunnel. But whenever that happens, you find yourself in a bigger tunnel." + text

Step 2:

> Base64 decrypt
>  "Is this the big tunnel? That was the hexagonal tunnel, but there's more...." + text

Text at this point:

> ```
> 252525252520252525252420403E25252520252525252520253C213E252025252E3C25202525252440203E25252525203C213E25252025252E252E203C2525252420403E252525DA3C213E252E203C252525252025252525252024403E40402040404040402040403C213E2040402E3C2520252525252520252524403E202525252525202525253C21203E25252525DA2525252525202E3C2525252024403E252520253C213E25202E3C252525202525252525202524403E40204040404040204040403C21203E40402E3C202525252525202525252524DA403E25252520252525252520253C213E252025252E3C2520252524403E204040403C21203E4040402E204040402E3C202525252525202525252440203E4040404020404040403CDA213E4040402040402E3C2520252525252520252524403E202525252525202525253C21203E25252E2520252525252520252E40402E202E40402E3C202525252440203E2525253CDA213E2525252025252E252E203C252525252025252525252024403E40402040404040402040403C213E204040402E3C20252525252520252525252420403E252525202525252525DA253C213E252025252E252E2040404040402040402E2E40204040404040204040402E2520252525252520252E3C2525202525252525202524403E402040404040402040403C213EDA40404040402040404040402040402E3C2520252525252520252524403E202525252525202525253C21203E2525252520252525252520252525252520252E404040204040404040DA402E3C2525202525252525202524403E402040404040402040403C213E20404040404020402E3C2525202525252525202524403E252025252525252025253C213E20252E3C2525DA2524403E252025253C213E2025252E2E3C20252525252520252524403E2040404040402040403C213E204040404040204040404040204040402E3C202525252440203E4040403CDA213E4040402040402E3C252025252525252024403E252520252525253C20213E25252520252525252520252E3C252520252524403E20252525253C20213E25252520252E3C2525DA252524403E20252525253C20213E252525202525252525202E3C252525202524403E40204040403C21203E40404040204040402E252025252E3C2520252525252520252524403EDA4040404040204040403C21203E4040404020402E3C2525202525252525202524403E252025252525252025253C213E202525252525202525252525202525252525202E402E4040DA40404040402040402E3C2520252525252520252524403E204040404040204040403C21203E4040404020402E3C2525202525252525202524403E252025252525252025253C213EDA2525252525202525252525202525252E2520252E252525202E3C2525252024403E404020403C213E40204040402E3C20252525252520252524403E2040404040402040403C213EDA404040404020402E3CDA
> 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
> ```

Step 3:

> Hex to Ascii
>  No flavor message to indicate correct path. Which might indicate a mistake.
>  First block has a 7 character alphabet `%$@<!>.`
>  Second block has a 3 character alphabet. `?!.`
> `%%%%% %%%%$ @>%%% %%%%% %<!>% %%.<% %%%$@ >%%%% <!>%% %%.%. <%%%$ @>%%%Ú`
> `<!>%. <%%%% %%%%% $@>@@ @@@@@ @@<!> @@.<% %%%%% %%$@> %%%%% %%%<! >%%%%Ú`
> `%%%%% .<%%% $@>%% %<!>% .<%%% %%%%% %$@>@ @@@@@ @@@<! >@@.< %%%%% %%%%$Ú`
> `@>%%% %%%%% %<!>% %%.<% %%$@> @@@<! >@@@. @@@.< %%%%% %%%$@ >@@@@ @@@@<Ú`
> `!>@@@ @@.<% %%%%% %%$@> %%%%% %%%<! >%%.% %%%%% %.@@. .@@.< %%%$@ >%%%<Ú`
> `!>%%% %%.%. <%%%% %%%%% $@>@@ @@@@@ @@<!> @@@.< %%%%% %%%%$ @>%%% %%%%%Ú`
> `%<!>% %%.%. @@@@@ @@..@ @@@@@ @@@.% %%%%% %.<%% %%%%% %$@>@ @@@@@ @@<!>Ú`
> `@@@@@ @@@@@ @@.<% %%%%% %%$@> %%%%% %%%<! >%%%% %%%%% %%%%% %.@@@ @@@@@Ú`
> `@.<%% %%%%% %$@>@ @@@@@ @@<!> @@@@@ @.<%% %%%%% %$@>% %%%%% %%<!> %.<%%Ú`
> `%$@>% %%<!> %%..< %%%%% %%$@> @@@@@ @@<!> @@@@@ @@@@@ @@@.< %%%$@ >@@@<Ú`
> `!>@@@ @@.<% %%%%% $@>%% %%%%< !>%%% %%%%% %.<%% %%$@> %%%%< !>%%% %.<%%Ú`
> `%%$@> %%%%< !>%%% %%%%% .<%%% %$@>@ @@@<! >@@@@ @@@.% %%.<% %%%%% %%$@>Ú`
> `@@@@@ @@@<! >@@@@ @.<%% %%%%% %$@>% %%%%% %%<!> %%%%% %%%%% %%%%% .@.@@Ú`
> `@@@@@ @@.<% %%%%% %%$@> @@@@@ @@@<! >@@@@ @.<%% %%%%% %$@>% %%%%% %%<!>Ú`
> `%%%%% %%%%% %%%.% %.%%% .<%%% $@>@@ @<!>@ @@@.< %%%%% %%$@> @@@@@ @@<!>Ú`
> `@@@@@ @.<Ú`
> `...............Ú`
> `.!?!!.?........Ú`
> `........?.?!.?.Ú`
> `.....!.?.......Ú`
> `......!?!!.?...Ú`
> `.........?.?!.?Ú`
> `...............Ú`
> `.!.!!!.!!!!!!!!Ú`
> `!!!!!!!.?......Ú`
> `.!?!!.?......?.Ú`
> `?!.?....!.?....Ú`
> `.....!?!!.?!!!!Ú`
> `!!!!?.?!.?!!!.?Ú`
> `.........!?!!.?Ú`
> `........?.?!.?.Ú`
> `.....!.!!!.?...Ú`
> `...............Ú`
> `.!?!!.?!!!!!!!!Ú`
> `!!!!!!!!!!?.?!.Ú`
> `?!!!.!!!.?.....Ú`
> `..........!?!!.Ú`
> `?..............Ú`
> `?.?!.?.........Ú`
> `.......!.?.....Ú`
> `....!?!!.?.....Ú`
> `...?.?!.?......Ú`
> `......!........Ú`
> `.....!.?.......Ú`
> `............!?!Ú`
> `!.?!!!!!!!!!!!!Ú`
> `!!!!!!?.?!.?!!!Ú`
> `!!!!!!.?.......Ú`
> `..........!?!!.Ú`
> `?..............Ú`
> `..?.?!.?.......Ú`
> `.........!.!!!!Ú`
> `!!!!!!!!!!!.?..Ú`
> `.......!?!!.?..Ú`
> `......?.?!.?...Ú`
> `.......!.?.....Ú`
> `....!?!!.?!!!!!Ú`
> `!!!?.?!.?!!!.?.Ú`
> `...............Ú`
> `.!?!!.?!!!!!!!!Ú`
> `!!!!!!!!?.?!.?!Ú`
> `!!!!!!!!!!.?...Ú`
> `..............!Ú`
> `?!!.?..........Ú`
> `......?.?!.?...Ú`
> `.........!.....Ú`
> `..............!Ú`
> `.............!.Ú`
> `!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Ú`
> `.?.......!?!!.?Ú`
> `!!!!!!?.?!.?!!!Ú`
> `.?.............Ú`
> `....!?!!.?!!!!!Ú`
> `!!!!!!!!!!!?.?!Ú`
> `.?!!!!!!!!!.?..Ú`
> `...............Ú`
> `..!?!!.?.......Ú`
> `...........?.?!Ú`
> `.?.............Ú`
> `...!.?.......!?Ú`
> `!!.?!!!!!!?.?!.Ú`
> `?!!!...........Ú`
> `..!.!!!!!!!.?..Ú`
> `...............Ú`
> `..!?!!.?!!!!!!!Ú`
> `!!!!!!!!!!!?.?!Ú`
> `.?!!!.?........Ú`
> `...........!?!!Ú`
> `.?.............Ú`
> `.....?.?!.?....Ú`
> `........!.?....Ú`
> `.....!?!!.?!!!!Ú`
> `!!!!?.?!.?!!!!!Ú`
> `!!!!!!!!.?.....Ú`
> `....!?!!.?.....Ú`
> `...?.?!.?......Ú`
> `..........!.?..Ú`
> `...............Ú`
> `..!?!!.?!!!!!!!Ú`
> `!!!!!!!!!!!?.?!Ú`
> `.?!!!!!!!!!!!!!Ú`
> `!!!!.?.........Ú`
> `........!?!!.?.Ú`
> `...............Ú`
> `?.?!.?.........Ú`
> `.........!.....Ú`
> `......!........Ú`
> `.....!.!!!!!!!!Ú`
> `!!!.?..........Ú`
> `.......!?!!.?!!Ú`
> `!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?Ú`
> `.?!.?!!!.!.!.!.Ú`
> `?.......!?!!.?!Ú`
> `!!!!!?.?!.?!!!!Ú`
> `!!!!!!!.?......Ú`
> `...........!?!!Ú`
> `.?.............Ú`
> `...?.?!.?..!.?.Ú`
> `......!?!!.?...Ú`
> `...?.?!.?......Ú`
> `..!...!........Ú`
> `...!.?.......!?Ú`
> `!!.?!!!!!!?.?!.Ú`
> `?!!!!!!!.!!!!!!Ú`
> `!.?.......!?!!.Ú`
> `?......?.?!.?..Ú`
> `......!.?......Ú`
> `.............!?Ú`
> `!!.?!!!!!!!!!!!Ú`
> `!!!!!!!?.?!.?!!Ú`
> `!.?............Ú`
> `.......!?!!.?..Ú`
> `...............Ú`
> `.?.?!.?......!.Ú`
> `..!.!!!!!!!!!!!Ú`
> `!!!!.!.!!!!!!!!Ú`
> `!!!!!!!!!!!....Ú`
> `...........!.?.Ú`
> `..............!Ú`
> `?!!.?!!!!!!!!!!Ú`
> `!!!!?.?!.?!!!!!Ú`
> `!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Ú`
> `!!!!!!!.?......Ú`
> `.!?!!.?!!!!!!?.Ú`
> `?!.?!!!!!!!!!!!Ú`
> `.?.........!?!!Ú`
> `.?!!!!!!!!?.?!.Ú`
> `?!!!!!!!.!!!!!!Ú`
> `!.?............Ú`
> `...!?!!.?......Ú`
> `........?.?!.?.Ú`
> `...............Ú`
> `..!.?..........Ú`
> `...!?!!.?......Ú`
> `......?.?!.?...Ú`
> `...........!.!!Ú`
> `!.?............Ú`
> `.....!?!!.?!!!!Ú`
> `!!!!!!!!!!!!?.?Ú`
> `!.?!!!!!!!!!!!!Ú`
> `!!!.?..........Ú`
> `.......!?!!.?..Ú`
> `..............?Ú`
> `.?!.?..........Ú`
> `...............Ú`
> `.!.?...........Ú`
> `........!?!!.?!Ú`
> `!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Ú`
> `!!?.?!.?!!!!!!!Ú`
> `.?.............Ú`
> `......!?!!.?...Ú`
> `...............Ú`
> `?.?!.?.........Ú`
> `...!.!!!!!!!!!!Ú`
> `!!!!!!!.......!Ú`
> `.!.............Ú`
> `..!.?..........Ú`
> `.......!?!!.?!!Ú`
> `!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?Ú`
> `.?!.?!!!!!!!!!!Ú`
> `!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Ú`
> `!!.?.......!?!!Ú`
> `.?!!!!!!?.?!.?!Ú`
> `!!!!!!.?.......Ú`
> `............!?!Ú`
> `!.?............Ú`
> `......?.?!.?...Ú`
> `.............!.Ú`
> `?.......!?!!.?!Ú`
> `!!!!!?.?!.?!!!.Ú`
> `............!.?Ú`
> `...............Ú`
> `....!?!!.?!!!!!Ú`
> `!!!!!!!!!!!!!?.Ú`
> `?!.?!!!!!!!!!.?Ú`
> `...............Ú`
> `..!?!!.?.......Ú`
> `.........?.?!.?Ú`
> `........!.?....Ú`
> `...!?!!.?......Ú`
> `?.?!.?....!.!!!Ú`
> `.?.............Ú`
> `....!?!!.?!!!!!Ú`
> `!!!!!!!!!!!?.?!Ú`
> `.?!!!!!!!!!!!!!Ú`
> `!!.?...........Ú`
> `......!?!!.?...Ú`
> `.............?.Ú`
> `?!.?...........Ú`
> `...............Ú`
> `!.?............Ú`
> `.......!?!!.?!!Ú`
> `!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Ú`
> `!?.?!.?!!!!!!!.Ú`
> `?..............Ú`
> `...!?!!.?......Ú`
> `..........?.?!.Ú`
> `?..............Ú`
> `..!.!!!!!!!!!!!Ú`
> `!!!!.?.........Ú`
> `!?!!.?........?Ú`
> `.?!.?..........Ú`
> `!.?.........!?!Ú`
> `!.?!!!!!!!!?.?!Ú`
> `.?!!!.?........Ú`
> `.........!?!!.?Ú`
> `!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Ú`
> `!?.?!.?!!!!!!!!Ú`
> `!!!.?..........Ú`
> `.........!?!!.?Ú`
> `...............Ú`
> `...?.?!.?......Ú`
> `!.!!!!!!!!!!!.?Ú`
> `...............Ú`
> `..!?!!.?!!!!!!!Ú`
> `!!!!!!!!!?.?!.?Ú`
> `!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Ú`
> `!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Ú`
> `!.?............Ú`
> `.......!?!!.?..Ú`
> `...............Ú`
> `.?.?!.?....!.!!Ú`
> `!!!!!!!.!!!!!!!Ú`
> `.?.......!?!!.?Ú`
> `......?.?!.?..!Ú`
> `.?.........!?!!Ú`
> `.?!!!!!!!!?.?!.Ú`
> `?!!!.?.........Ú`
> `........!?!!.?!Ú`
> `!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Ú`
> `?.?!.?!!!!!!!!!Ú`
> `!!.?...........Ú`
> `......!?!!.?...Ú`
> `.............?.Ú`
> `?!.?...........Ú`
> `.......!.?.....Ú`
> `..!?!!.?......?Ú`
> `.?!.?....!.?...Ú`
> `..............!Ú`
> `?!!.?!!!!!!!!!!Ú`
> `!!!!!!?.?!.?!!!Ú`
> `!!!!!!!!!!.?...Ú`
> `....!?!!.?!!!!!Ú`
> `!?.?!.?!!!!!!!!Ú`
> `!!!.?.Ú`

Comment: First section is in groups of 72, second is in groups of 16.

Comment: @2012rcampion Are you assuming or do you know?  I would have thought 17 for the second group (unless you're counting the U-thing as a space)

Comment: Bunch of Symbols. Hmm, what other stuff uses a whole bunch of symbols? Maybe some other encrypting thing that has characters to be replaced... Hmm.....

Comment: @bleh No need to spoil your own puzzle. :)

Comment: Just assuming, by looking at the evenly-spaced occurrences of `DA`.

Comment: @LeppyR64 Don't know how a space turns into a Uthing.... Its a space

Comment: @bleh Are you trying to give me a hint?  Using the output from step 2 as hex and converting it to ascii, yields the Uthing (`DA`).  I don't know any encodings that encode the `DA` as a space character but I'm reasonably certain that I have not done the right thing for step 3 because there was no continuation of the message.

Comment: @LeppyR64 0x0D + 0x0A is \r\n

Comment: Completely ignoring spaces and `Ú`s leaves
repeating, but nonperiodic, patterns.
The first repeating delimiter sequence
seems to be `$@>`-`<!>`-`.`(none or more)-`.<`.
The second seems to be `!?!!.?`-`?.?!.?`-`!.`(none or more)-`!.?.`.
Also, the data before the first delimiter in each pattern is redundant.

Comment: Ok. What else has a 7 char alphabet?

Comment: Music and [7-segment digital displays](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:7_segment_display_labeled.svg) have A,@bleh,C,D,E,F,G